# commit id associated with git tag using Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, git-tag

I have a git tag as input. I want commit id associated with that git tag as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your tag name to the filter `filter=tags/tagname`

full example:

```
"https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$($repoName)/refs?filter=tags/$($tag)&api-version=6.0"
```